# rds replica error when creating in different vpc with terraform failing

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a read replica of an rds database in a different region via terraform. I am able to achieve via the AWS console, however when applying through Terraform (0.14.10) the apply fails with the following:

Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-xxx and the EC2 security group is in vpc-yyy

TF block:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "replica" {
   count                  = var.enable_peering_read_replica ? 1 : 0
   name                   = db-replica
   identifier             = db-replica
   replicate_source_db    = source-db
   instance_class         = "db.t3.small"
   apply_immediately      = true
   publicly_accessible    = false
   skip_final_snapshot    = true
   vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.peering_sg.id]
}
```

For the replicate_source_db I have used the arn and the db name, but still get the same error.

Comment: What is the full resource code and the exact error message?

Comment: Updated with the TF source and full error

Comment: You Have to provide full code with vpc and your security groups

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one and made me suffer a lot. Even when there are many threads similar to this one around there, none of them led me to the complete solution.
The full explanation is the following. There are two possible scenarios:

1. The database replica will be created in the same region as the source database.
2. The database replica will be created in a different region than the source database.

Scenario 2 is the point of this post and it's the one I was trying to cover too. These are the facts:

- For **replicate_source_db**, specify a valid DB instance ARN. [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstanceReadReplica.html).
- **db_subnet_group_name**: The DB instance will be created in the VPC associated with the DB subnet group. If unspecified, it will be created in the default VPC, or in EC2 Classic, if available. When working with read replicas, it should be specified only if the source database specifies an instance in another AWS Region. [db_instance module doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#db_subnet_group_name)
- And last but not least, even with the above options correctly set the read replica is created in the default VPC. Why? The answer is that there is another configuration that is crucial to achieving the desired goal, **cross_region_replica**. The default value of this property is false and it was the cause of all my confusion. We need to set it to true.

For a complete set of examples that really work, check [Same region example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/blob/master/examples/replica-postgres/main.tf) and [Different region example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/blob/master/examples/cross-region-replica-postgres/main.tf)

Answer (score 0):

The error msg is clear: Your DB and the security group are in **different VPCs**. This means that you can't associate them. Your security group `aws_security_group.peering_sg.id` (definition not shown) must be in the **same VPC** as your DB.

Comment: it allows me to do this via the console, i.e select the security group in a different vpc, this is required as the replica needs to be in a different vpc.

Comment: I have been able to deploy the required resources, (new vpc, vpc peer, subnets and security group) via tf then create the read replica within this vpc via the console. however via terraform it fails but the values are the same as when doing it via the console

Comment: @einonsy You have to provide all relevant TF code. Its clearly not the same as in AWS console.